# Regular expressions, sas

Tags: regex, sas

I am looking at someone elses code and have a question. Below is the code. Where it says: ^DR DUE does that mean the string starts with DR DUE? I am new to perl regular expressions. Also, where ATM/(DEP|WTD) does this mean match ATM/(DEP|WTD) in the string? However, I thought that ( and ) were metacharacters too. Thanks for your help!

```
Removed
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will match a string containing

- the string "COAL"
- "DR DUE TO ATM/" placed at beginning of line and followed by "DEP" or "WTD".

So it will match:

- COAL
- (beginning of line)DR DUE TO ATM/DEP ERROR
- (beginning of line)DR DUE TO ATM/WTD ERROR

Comment: There are tools that visualize regexps to make them easier to understand, e.g.: https://regexper.com/#%2FCOAL%7C%5EDR%20DUE%20TO%20ATM%5C%2F%28DEP%7CWTD%29%20ERROR%2F -- maybe that would be helpful.